# Creating a number station

Tags: sound

This is a question about manipulating sound (wav files).

The goal is to produce something that sounds like a number station broadcast,
see e.g., 4:00 in http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdnoAJ7KoFE

It is easy to generate a random string of numbers,
and send it to the linux program `espeak` (with `-v de` for German and `-w out.wav` for saving the sound as a wav file.)

Now, the resulting voice is too clean to sound like a radio recording,
so the challenge is to distort the sound a bit and make it sound more like a strange radio recording. Adding a little echo and some white noise maybe?

Comment: Is this a *Mathematica*-related question? If so, please add information on what you already tried and working code.

Comment: I can't imagine you'll get any spies to pay attention to you if you use *random* numbers...

Comment: Oleksandr R. It is more that I enjoy the sound, (and creep out the neighbours) :)

Answer (score 6):

It shouldn't be too hard to do some simple sound processing. Take an example file:

```
data = ExampleData[{"Sound" , "Apollo13Problem"}]
```

[image: simple sound]

Get a short sequence of sample values from near the end of the file:

```
soundsamples = data[[1, 1]][[All, 110000 ;; -2000]];
```

It looks OK:

```
ListLinePlot[{soundsamples[[1]]}]
```

[image: listplot]

Play it without modifications:

```
ListPlay[soundsamples, SampleRate -> 11000]
```

[image: the basic sound]

Change the data:

```
ListPlay[BandpassFilter[soundsamples[[1]], {1, 2.5}], SampleRate -> 11000]
ListPlay[DerivativeFilter[soundsamples[[1]], {3}], SampleRate -> 11000]
ListPlay[GradientFilter[soundsamples[[1]], {1, .6}], SampleRate -> 11000]
```

[image: three sound plots]

Making it sound even worse shouldn't be too hard.  It's making it sound better that's difficult... :)